# US editors and reviewers vs. Iranian authors?

Tags: publications, ethics

Could you please let me know your opinion about the following?

> ---
>
> Subject: US editors and reviewers can no longer handle submissions by authors
>   employed by the Government of Iran
>
> ---
>
> OFAC Sanctions
>
> US editors and reviewers can no longer handle submissions by authors
>   employed by the Government of Iran
>
> Dear Dr Bruno Granier,
>
> The Office of Foreign Assets Control (OFAC) of the US Department of 
>   the Treasury administers and enforces economic and trade sanctions. As
>   a result of OFAC sanctions we have been made aware that US editors, US
>   Elsevier staff and US reviewers are now unable to handle scientific 
>   manuscripts where any of the authors are employed by the Government of
>   Iran. This includes the research departments of the various oil and
>   gas  companies which are deemed to be entities of the Government of
>   Iran.  We realize that this OFAC regulation will cause some
>   inconvenience in your role as an editor but Elsevier is legally
>   obliged to ensure that  all reasonable efforts are made to avoid
>   submissions from Iranian  government agencies and companies being
>   handled by US editors, US  Elsevier staff and US reviewers.  Please be
>   aware that editors, Elsevier staff and reviewers from outside the US
>   may still handle these  manuscripts and that this OFAC regulation does
>   not pertain to  manuscripts where the authors are based at Iranian
>   academic and research institutes.  Manuscripts originating from a
>   clinical setting that are  not government run, for example, a hospital
>   or clinical practice are  also exempt from this regulation.
>
> To view the official OFAC regulation, please click here.  In practice
>   the result of these sanctions will mean that:
>
> - Submissions where any author is based in Iran, and is not at an  academic and research institution, cannot be handled by US-based 
>     editors, US Elsevier staff, US reviewers, or any US citizens based 
>     outside of the US.
> - If an Iranian author has dual affiliations (eg.  university and  government), their submission cannot be handled by US-based editors,
>     US  Elsevier staff, US reviewers, or any US citizens based outside of
>     the  US.
> - Affiliations of Iranian authors should therefore be checked, and any manuscripts which fall under this OFAC regulation delegated to a
>     non-US editor, before handling.
> - When assigning reviewers, affiliations of Iranian authors should  also be checked, and any papers which fall under this OFAC regulation 
>     should only be sent to non-US reviewers. (As an editor you should do 
>     what is reasonable to determine the nationality of a reviewer e.g.
>     check their email address. This check does not extend to emailing
>     reviewers  directly to confirm their nationality or location). Unless
>     there is  specific knowledge that a non-US-based reviewer is a US
>     citizen, editors can send such submissions to reviewers based outside
>     the US.
> - If your journal workflow involves all submissions being handled by  US-based Elsevier staff, they will reject these manuscripts outright 
>     before they reach you.
> - Should there be no suitably qualified editor or reviewer, please reject the manuscript outright.
>
>   When rejecting manuscripts which fall under this OFAC regulation 
>     please use the new EES Decision Term "Reject - OFAC Sanctions" and the
>     following text:
>
>   "As a result of OFAC sanctions all editorial staff who are 
>     US-based/US nationals are unable to handle scientific manuscripts
>     which  are authored by Iranian scientists, employed by the Government
>     of Iran.  Based on this OFAC regulation we are unfortunately unable to
>     handle your manuscript. We wish you success with your submission to
>     another  Journal."
>
> We apologize for the inconvenience this may cause. If you do have any
>   questions please contact your Publisher.
>
> Sent on behalf of Dan Lovegrove
>
> Cretaceous Research

Comment: Here is the source: http://mail.elsevier-alerts.com/go.asp?/bESJ001/mTR68G9F/uQX51PJB/xD82RH9F

Comment: *“Let me know your opinion about”* is definitely not a good type of question for this Q&A site…

Comment: Yes, this is tragic and stupid (and done before by IEEE), and yay Elsevier again, but there's no actual question here. Voting to close.

Comment: I am in agreement with the close votes: "Please give an opinion" does _not_ ask a question. If there is an edit which provides an answerable question, rather than just asking for political opinions or bloviating, we can reopen.

Comment: One more thing to note: given that the restriction does _not_ apply to academics, the effects of such a ban are likely to be minimal.